# Randomizing a two-dimensional array inside a loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, shuffle

I have data stored in a two-dimensional array containing the country's name and capital city. I would want to loop through the array, and display each country's name, and the other countries' (not the current country's) capitals (which are to be sorted in random order). Inside the loop, the country's capitals are sorted in random order using a function `shuffle()`. But this function appears to be causing duplicate array items to be displayed (for example, a country (in `arr[i][0]` in the loop below), like `Vietnam`, erroneously appears twice):

```js
var masterlist = [
  ["Indonesia", "Jakarta"],
  ["Malaysia", "Kuala Lumpur"],
  ["Philippines", "Manila"],
  ["Singapore", "Singapore"],
  ["Thailand", "Bangkok"],
  ["Vietnam", "Hanoi"],
  ["China", "Beijing"],
  ["Japan", "Tokyo"],
  ["South Korea", "Seoul"],
  ["Taiwan", "Taipei"]
];

/* Randomize array in-place using Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm */
function shuffle(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

for (var i = 0; i < masterlist.length; i++) {
  //console.log("masterlist[i][0]", masterlist[i][0]);

  var arr = shuffle(masterlist); // create a shuffled copy of the array; ERROR here; the shuffle function inside this loop causes duplicate masterlist items
  //console.log(arr[i][0]);

  // save as new array the masterlist with the item's capital removed (ONLY to be used for choosing other nations' capitals in random order):
  var filteredArr = arr.filter(function(e) {
    return e !== arr[i]
  })

  console.log(arr[i][0], filteredArr); // ERROR here; should give unique country, then all other nations' capitals in random order

  var correctItem = arr[i];
  //console.log("correctItem", correctItem);

}
```

Comment: Shuffle ONCE, THEN do the loop.
Inside the loop, shuffle the filtered array.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need?

1. Loop countries
2. For each country get Array with all capitals except the current
3. Shuffle the result
4. Do whatever you like with country + capitals, in my example just console.log

```js
var masterlist = [
  ["Indonesia", "Jakarta"],
  ["Malaysia", "Kuala Lumpur"],
  ["Philippines", "Manila"],
  ["Singapore", "Singapore"],
  ["Thailand", "Bangkok"],
  ["Vietnam", "Hanoi"],
  ["China", "Beijing"],
  ["Japan", "Tokyo"],
  ["South Korea", "Seoul"],
  ["Taiwan", "Taipei"]
];

/* Randomize array in-place using Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm */
function shuffle(array) {
  for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    var temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
  }
  return array;
}

for (var i = 0; i < masterlist.length; i++) {

  var country = masterlist[i][0];
  var countryArr = [];

  for (var j = 0; j < masterlist.length; j++) {
    if (i !== j) countryArr.push(masterlist[j][1]);
  }

  countryArr = shuffle(countryArr);

  console.log({
    [country]: countryArr
  });
}
```

Comment: iAmOren's comment was the solution I was looking for, but thank you very much for the help and more efficient code.